# Webservice field validation (for external use)?

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, asp.net-web-api

We've been working on a ASP.NET webservice for customers.

For local testing, ASP.NET on localhost allows us to enter field values directly on the ASP.NET supplied webpage, visible at:

https://www.example.com/webservices/customer/webservice.asmx?op=PlaceOrder

```
<UserIDNumber>long</UserIDNumber>
<CustomerEmailAddress>string</CustomerEmailAddress>
<CustomerFirstName>string</CustomerFirstName>
<CustomerLastName>string</CustomerLastName>
```

We have some custom field validation. E.g.

- If CustomerEmailAddress is not a valid email address syntax (e.g. no '@') we return "Not a valid user email address."
- If CustomerEmailAddress = "", we return "Enter a CustomerEmailAddress."
- If CustomerFirstName = "" we return "Enter a user CustomerFirstName."

If the user however enters 'hello' for the  field, ASP.NET throws:

```
System.ArgumentException: Cannot convert hello to System.Int64.
Parameter name: type ---> System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.
   at System.Number.StringToNumber(String str, NumberStyles options, NumberBuffer& number, NumberFormatInfo info, Boolean parseDecimal)
   at System.Number.ParseInt64(String value, NumberStyles options, NumberFormatInfo numfmt)
   at System.String.System.IConvertible.ToInt64(IFormatProvider provider)
   at System.Convert.ChangeType(Object value, Type conversionType, IFormatProvider provider)
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.ScalarFormatter.FromString(String value, Type type)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.ScalarFormatter.FromString(String value, Type type)
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.ValueCollectionParameterReader.Read(NameValueCollection collection)
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.HtmlFormParameterReader.Read(HttpRequest request)
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.HttpServerProtocol.ReadParameters()
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.WebServiceHandler.CoreProcessRequest()
```

Shall we rather then specify:

```
<UserIDNumber>string</UserIDNumber>
```

Though in the webservice documentation we give to the customer say it requires a long number?

Then in code we could use:

```
Val(strUserIDNumber)>=1
```

to check if it's a number. And if not say:

"Enter a valid number for UserIDNumber."

Comment: Can you share the code which does the validation?

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya Currently something like "If lngUserID>0 Then Return True Else Return False". Noting that lngUserIDNumber is a Long.

Comment: `If Long.TryParse(userInput, LongVariable) Then`

Comment: @Mary Yes that's whatI thought thanks. My real question is, when the webservice consumer sees the asmx schema online (as opposed to our documentation), will they get confused when they see it as a String rather than a Long? And so what is normal practice for this type of thing?

Answer (score 0):

To make your validations easier, you can make use of [FluentValidation](https://fluentvalidation.net/)

Example:

```
public class CustomerValidator : AbstractValidator<Customer> {
  public CustomerValidator() {
    RuleFor(x => x.Surname).NotEmpty();
    RuleFor(x => x.UserIDNumber).NotEmpty().WithMessage("Enter a valid number for UserIDNumber");
    RuleFor(x => x.Discount).NotEqual(0).When(x => x.HasDiscount);
    RuleFor(x => x.Address).Length(20, 250);
    RuleFor(x => x.Postcode).Must(BeAValidPostcode).WithMessage("Please specify a valid postcode");
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

`Val(strUserIDNumber)>=1` will throw an error if a string that cannot be converted to a number is passed in.

Check if the string passed in for the ID can be converted to a number then validate the email.

Example:

```
// validate userID
long userID = 0;
if( long.TryParse(strUserIDNumber, out userID) == false)
{
   return "Not a valid userID";
}
```

```
//validate your email... something like this 
if (!CustomerEmailAddress.Contains("@"))
   return "Not a valid user email";
else if(CustomerEmailAddress == "")
   return "Enter a CustomerEmailAddress.";
```

Comment: Thanks but: Val("a")=0 according to https://www.jdoodle.com/compile-vb-dot-net-online/